# Dialog rendered behind Home Activity

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on a complex Android app and found a strange problem.
The problem occurs when I start an activity to show a dialog.

### What have I tried

I tried to search for similar problems ("Android activity blocked by home activity" etc) but could not find any.

Due to the complex nature of my app, I still cannot find the minimum representation of the cause -- The *Description* section below cannot be used to reproduce the problem. It is just something that I think is closely related to the problem. The real cause could be interactions between different subsystems.

### Description

The activity is launched by a service with intent flags = `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, which ensures that it will be the topmost activity at the point when it's launched. In its `onCreate` method, the activity set its window flags to be `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_FULLSCREEN | FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`, which ensures that even if the screen is locked, the activity will still be displayed. The dialog is also built and shown in the activity's `onCreate` method.

The app is tested on Android phones with screen pattern locks using the following steps:

1. Start the app. Press home button to return to the home activity. Remove the app from the recent app list.
2. Turn off and lock the screen by pressing the power button.
3. Ask (through GCM, to be specific) the service to launch the activity once. Dialog is then successfully shown.
4. Don't click any button on the dialog. Lock the screen again.
5. Ask the service to launch the activity once more. This time the dialog is also shown but instantly disappears, leaving the screen pattern lock shown.
6. Unlock the pattern lock and something strange appears: The dialog is now shown behind the home activity. The dialog doesn't respond to touch event. It's just like a wallpaper.

[image: Illustration of the screen when the problem occurs]

### Android Version seems to matter

The problem seems to be only affecting some of the versions. It occurred on a Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.4.2) but didn't occur on a Galaxy Tab 3 (Android 4.1).

Comment: The z-order for dialogs is determined by the order in which they are created.  I'm guessing that when your screen lock comes on, in some cases, its stopping the underlying activity, and recreating it, ontop of the old dialog.

Not sure how to bring a dialog to the front, but perhaps you can destroy the old dialog and recreate it on the pattern lock release?

Comment: @NameSpace Thanks for you advice. Let me try it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally the problem was solved by removing the line

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

for the activity containing the dialog from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I am not sure why it could be solved in this way though.