# Dialog activity going behind the launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, launcher

**I have a Dialog Activity with selectable text.**

[image]

**when i tap outside the dialog it goes below the launcher before sliding away to the top.**

[image]

code for my activity theme is

```
<style name="popup_theme" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

</style>
```

And intent flags that i am using to start Activity are:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DictionaryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("word",message);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

For animating exit i am using

```
 @Override
    public void finish() {

        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0,R.anim.dialog_exit);

    }
```

dialog_exit.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

What did I miss.How can I take focus back to the Dialog activity (Through it goes behind only at exit animation still its not looking cool)

Comment: Seems I have got [the same problem as you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166518/dialog-rendered-behind-home-activity). Just remove the style line and the problem will be solved.